# I need to move one side of the polygon back 1 meter - QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon

I need to move one side of a polygon up by 1 meter on QGIS as seen in the picture. So the size of the polygon will decrease. Is there any way to do this? I can edit the polygon with the vertex tool, but I need to do it with a clear measurement.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could create a new line object along the edge of the polygon that needs to be moved (you could use the snap tool to ensure the new line object is exactly the same as the polygon edge), then create a 1m buffer around the line object, and then use the buffer polygon to clip your original polygon?

Comment: I will try this. But I wonder if there is a practical method that I can drag it directly and measure it at the same time. QGIS does much more, but sometimes I have to do this many times a day.